# Book in which people would step into a booth that made them grow younger

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book about a booth that people could step in and activate and the top dome would swirl dust around, but the booth wouldn't transport you anywhere. After a time, the people would notice that they were growing younger.

I think it was a *[Perry Rhodan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan)* book, but cannot be sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: Perry Rhodan has something vaguely similar (https://www.perrypedia.de/wiki/Zelldusche and https://www.perrypedia.de/wiki/Zelldusche_(PR_Neo) respectively for the reboot series), but that did not make people younger, it just stopped aging at the current stage. Also people were aware of the purpose before using it.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 22):

You may be thinking of Larry Niven's [A World Out of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_World_Out_of_Time), previously discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265435/story-id-enslaved-geriatric-protagonist-hides-in-abandoned-but-still-functiona/265436#265436)

**I remember reading a book about a booth that people could step in and activate and the top dome would swirl dust around, but the booth wouldn't transport you anywhere. After a time, the people would notice that they were growing younger.**

In the Niven book, there are teleportation booths, but some of them don't take you anywhere distant; instead they transport away the accumulated toxins in a person's body, which look like dust left behind. It's only after several days that Niven's hero realizes that he's become younger physically.

Here's the scene when the hero uses the booth (to try to escape, thinking it is a conventional teleport booth):

> The lights were still on in the vault. Indicator lights glowed on the
> console. With luck the booths would work too. He stepped into one and
> looked for the dial.
>
> No dial, just a button set in a slender post. No choice about where he
> was going. Corbell wondered if the Norn would be waiting at the other
> end. He made himself push the button anyway.
>
> Nothing happened.
>
> He cursed luridly, pushed out of the booth and tried the other. **The
> second booth didn’t even have a door, and there was fine dust floating**
> **in it.** What the hell?